# \resizebox gives compile error when used with tikz matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, luatex, tikz-matrix

This MWE compile using lualatex with no error

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{matrix} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[draw=red,nodes=draw,column sep=2mm, row sep=2mm]
{
       \node (11) {};     & \node (12) {A};  & \node (13) {};  \\
       \node (21) {};     & \node (22) {B};  & \node (23) {};  \\
};

\draw  (12) -- (22);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But when adding `\resizebox` it now gives compile error:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{matrix} 
\begin{document}
 
\resizebox{.9\textwidth}{1.2\textwidth}
{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[draw=red,nodes=draw,column sep=2mm, row sep=2mm]
{
       \node (11) {};     & \node (12) {A};  & \node (13) {};  \\
       \node (21) {};     & \node (22) {B};  & \node (23) {};  \\
};

\draw  (12) -- (22);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

compiling with lualatex now gives

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \pgf@matrix@last@nextcell@options 
                                  
l.35 }
    
?
```

Note that this error *only* shows up when using tikz matrix. I've been using `\resizebox` to resize tikz pics for long time with no error.

This is the first time I try `\matrix` and this is how I found this.

Is it possible to use `\resizebox` with tikz pic which has `\matrix` in it?

TL 2023

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to define replacement for ampersands. Foe example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}

\resizebox{.9\textwidth}{1.2\textwidth}
{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[draw=red,nodes=draw,column sep=2mm, row sep=2mm,
        ampersand replacement=\&
        ]
{
       \node (11) {};     \& \node (12) {A};  \& \node (13) {};  \\
       \node (21) {};     \& \node (22) {B};  \& \node (23) {};  \\
};

\draw  (12) -- (22);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
Your matrix can be drawn by much shorter code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}

\resizebox{.9\textwidth}{1.2\textwidth}
{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells,
             draw=red,
             nodes=draw,
             column sep=2mm, row sep=2mm,
            ampersand replacement=\&
            ]
{
    \&  A   \&      \\
    \&  B   \&      \\
};
\draw  (m-1-2) -- (m-2-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

Result is the same as before.

Comment: Background: TikZ makes [`&` an active character](https://tikz.dev/tikz-matrices#sec-20.5) inside a matrix which is let to `\pgfmatrixnextcell`. If the matrix/the picture is now used in an argment, the usual problems occur. TikZ can't change the catcode of the input anymore. (PGF actually uses `\halign` and real `&` to build the matrix internally but two `&` for each column.)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel, thank you for explanation.